# java.io.IOException: No such file or directory when trying to use the command line programmatically

Tags: java, android, gpio

Common problem, I know, but I've tried every answer I've found. I'm trying to execute a command in the command line like so:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    onButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            runCommandAndAddOutput(getApplicationContext(), "output.txt", new String[]{"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio690/value"}, "Output");

        }
    });
}

private void runCommandAndAddOutput(final Context context, final String filename, final String[] command, final String tag) {

    File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    System.out.println(directory);
    int result = -1;
    File outputFile = new File(directory, filename);
    outputFile.setReadable(true, false);
    ProcessUtils.FileOutput commandOutput = new ProcessUtils.FileOutput(outputFile);


    result = ProcessUtils.runCommand(command, directory, tag, commandOutput);


    commandOutput.close();
    if (result == 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Command OK");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to generate output for '" + tag + "'");
    }
}


public class ProcessUtils {
    static public int runCommand(final String[] command, File workDir, String tag, OutputListener listener) {
        int result = -1;
        try {


            if (!workDir.getParentFile().exists()) {
                workDir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }

            if (!workDir.exists()) {
                workDir.createNewFile();
            }


            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            pb.directory(workDir);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);


            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader processOutputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            // Log ouput
            String readLine;
            while ((readLine = processOutputReader.readLine()) != null) {

                Log.i(tag, readLine);

                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onLine(readLine);
                }
            }
            result = p.exitValue();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failure", ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in the manifest, and I've confirmed that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns a valid directory, but I'm still getting directory not found exception on line `Process p = pb.start();`

Is there anything else I could be overlooking that could be causing this problem?

Comment: I know stupid but have you granted the permission ??

Comment: Always worth checking, but yes, I did.

Comment: Wild guess: `echo` doesn't exist as a separate command (it's usually/often implemented by the shell) and _quite possibly_ `runCommand` doesn't handle redirection (again, normally done by the shell).

Comment: Interesting. So would there be no way to trigger that implementation programmatically?

Comment: If you're just trying to send the line `1` to the file (device?) `/sys/class/gpio/gpio690/value` (which is what it _appears_ you're trying to do), then just opening the latter as a file and using `fputs` or similar should, I think do it.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what I'm trying to do under the hood. I'm trying to turn a peripheral on and off using GPIO and the only documentation I got was the above command. I believe it's supposed to change a value in that directory. How would I open it as a file?